# When should I prefer CursorAdapter over ArrayListAdapter, and when would it be the reverse?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

In type of situations will the usage of CursorAdapter make more sense over ArrayListAdapter, and when would it be the reverse?
The reasons may be performance wise, flexibility wise etc.

Answer (score 2):

cursor adpater when your source of data is from database and ArrayListAdapter when data extracted from data source is a simple list

Comment: Straightforward and simple :)